# How to make a custom focused effect be visible only if the keyboard navigation mode is on in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have to use a custom template for a WPF control (a RadioButton) and the control has to have a custom implementation of the Focused effect. Because of that don't use the `FocusVisualStyle` property but implement the effect inside the control template and I want to use the ControlTemplate's Triggers to enable or disable the effect like that:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="FocusEffect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But the problem is that the default Windows behaviour is that the focus effect is visible only when the keyboard navigation mode is on (the user used the Tab key or pressed the Alt key). If I use only the `IsKeyboardFocused` property, I have the effect even if the control has been clicked with the mouse which should not be the case.

Which property (properties) do I need to use as a trigger to achieve the default behaviour?

Comment: If you want to show that effect in the same situations as the default `FocusVisualStyle` were shown, why don't you just set a custome style to `FocusVisualStyle`?

Comment: The `FocusVisualStyle`, if I'm not missing anything, only allows drawing a rectangle around the whole control. I need to draw a rectangle only around the circle in a RadioButton, not around the content

Comment: Then create your custom template that removes the label.

Comment: @Paboka There is not such limitation. It merely defines the element overlayed over the RadioButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can freely design a Style for `FocusVisualStyle`. It merely defines a control to be overlayed.

A Style to surround the `RadioButton`'s mark would be like the following.

```xml
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Stroke="Black"
                           StrokeThickness="1"
                           StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>               
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}" Content="AAA"/>
    <RadioButton FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}" Content="BBB"/>
    <RadioButton FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}" Content="CCC"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can create alternative Styles as you wish.

Octagon:

```xml
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Polygon Points="1,0 3,0 4,1 4,3 3,4 1,4 0,3 0,1"
                             Stretch="Uniform"
                             Stroke="Black"
                             StrokeThickness="1"
                             StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Crosshair:

```xml
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>                
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                      UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <Path Data="M 1,0 L 1,2 M 0,1 L 2,1"
                          Stretch="Uniform"
                          Stroke="Gray"
                          StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Which property (properties) do I need to use as a trigger to achieve the default behaviour?

I am afraid there is no dependency property that you can use to determine whether last input was from the keyboard.

And yes, the `FocusVisualStyle` is programmatically applied as an adorner on top of the focused control.

So to solve this, you will need to implement some kind of focus detection functionality that programmatically focuses the element in your template.